# Split an Observable of list in two

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have an observable :

const allItems$: Observable<Items[]> = getAllItems();

The Items[] is something like : `[false, false, true, false]`

What I want is to split allItems in two Observables : `trueItems$ and falseItems$
What I'm currently doing is :

```
const allItems$: Observable<Items[]> = getAllItems();
const trueItems$ = allItems$.pipe(map(items => items.filter(item => !!item)));
const falseItems$ = allItems$.pipe(map(items => items.filter(item => !item)));
```

Note :  I'm using an angular `| async` to show the observables in the view.

It work fine but the problem is that the allItems observable is called twice (if I do a `console.log('hello')` inside the getAllItems() function, i will have 2 'hello' in the console.

Is it possible to do it cleaner and to split the 'allItems$' in two with only one 'hello' in console ?

Comment: What you're describing seems trickier than it seems. If you put log inside `getAllItems()` and you see two logs then the problem is not in RxJS here because RxJS will make two subscriptions to `allItems$` but it can't call the `getAllItems()`  for you. So it looks like this block of code is really called twice somewhere in your app. Only if you were returning a deffered Observable and the `console.log`  was inside its callback then it would make two logs but since you're not mentioning it I suppose you don't.

Comment: I believe that the fact I had 2 pipe async was like having 2 subscribtions resulting in double logging. The solution @Philipp Meissner gave did the trick for me

Comment: You did have two subscriptions but the function `getAllItems()` was called only once so if you saw two log messages then it depends on how the Observable returned is implemented and where the `console.log` was placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest solution would be to `share` the last emissions of `allItems$` so that all additional/late subscribers will not cause the source to replay again, but receive a buffered response.

```
const allItems$: Observable<Items[]> = getAllItems().pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

From here on just use it as you already did.

Read up on [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) and its behavior [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay).
Basically it shares the source and replays the specified amount of emissions to late/additional subscribers.

Comment: This is a great answer, but FYI with RxJS v7, the `shareReplay` is expected to be deprecated in favor of the `share` operator with configuration. See this for more information: https://medium.com/volosoft/whats-new-in-rxjs-7-a11cc564c6c0